# How to get all links in an HTML file containing a specific string

Tags: javascript, string

I have content of a html file.
I want in js to get all link that contain "do=download" in this page.
How i can do that?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If all your links are `<a>` tags then you could get them all the text of the tags using `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` then iterate over each, getting their  `.outerHTML` and checking the string using `includes`.

Comment: @LiamPillay of just do `const aLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='do= download']")].map(lnk=>lnk.getAttribute("href"));`

Comment: @mplungjan the more you know! Thanks for that.